Integrability of derivatives to deduce integrability of the function
$\varphi:[0,1] \to [0,1],$ is an absolutely continuous and increasing homeomorphism. If we have $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log ^2 \varphi^{\prime}(x)}{|x-1|^2} d x<\infty,$$
then do we have $$\int_0^1 \frac{|\varphi(x)-1|^2}{|x-1|^2} d x<\infty$$ hold?
The following is my attempt. Fix $M>0$, set $E=\left\{x \in[0,1]:\left|\log \varphi^{\prime}(x)\right| \geqslant M\right\}$, $F=\left\{x \in[0,1]:\left|\log \varphi^{\prime}(x)\right|<M\right\}$. Then $[0,1]=E\cup F\cup G$, where $G$ is a zero set and weighs nothing.
We have $\varphi^{\prime}(x) \leq C$ on $F$.
For $E$, $${\infty}>\int_E \frac{\log ^2 \varphi^{\prime}(x)}{|x-1|^2} d x\geq M^2 \int_E \frac{d x}{|x-1|^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow \quad \int_E \frac{d x}{|x-1|^2}<\infty.$$
Thus
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{|\varphi(x)-1|^2}{|x-1|^2} d x
 =&\int_E \frac{|\varphi(x)-1|^2}{\left|x-\left.1\right|^2\right.} d x+\int_F \frac{|\varphi(x)-1|^2}{|x-1|^2} d x \\
 \leq& 2  \int_E \frac{d x}{|x-1|^2}+\int_F \frac{|\varphi(x)-1|^2}{|x-1|^2} d x.
\end{align}
I hope the answer is affirmative but if a counterexample also works for me. Thank you very much.
